# How do I access both the value and accumulator of a Writer monad within a 'do' block (PureScript)?

Tags: monads, purescript, writer-monad

I'm learning about the Writer monad right now, and I'm not sure if it's correct to want to read both the value and the accumulator of the monad within a `do` block.  For example, in the coltzSeq function below I want to read the length of the Array accumulator as the final computation of the function.  Is it possible to do this or this an incorrect use of Writer?  Obviously, I could let the caller read the length of the final array, or I could use the State monad, but this is just an exercise for me.

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.Tuple
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Math (remainder, (%))
import Data.Int (toNumber, fromNumber)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (logShow)

coltz :: Number -> Number
coltz n = case (n % 2.0 == 0.0) of
            true  -> n / 2.0
            false -> 3.0 * n + 1.0

coltzW :: Number -> Writer (Array Number) Number
coltzW n = do
  tell [n]
  pure $ coltz n

-- Computes a coltz sequence and counts how many
-- steps it took to compute
coltzSeq :: Number -> Writer (Array Number) Int
coltzSeq n = do

  -- Can read the value in the writer
  -- but not the writer's internal state
  v <- (coltzW n)
  let l = 1

  -- Can read the value and the internal
  -- state, but it's not bound to the monad's context.
  -- let a = runWriter (coltzW n)
  -- let v = fst a
  -- let l = length (snd a)
  case (v) of
    1.0 -> pure $ l
    _ -> to1 v
```

Edit:
I tried gb.'s suggestion and tried using the `listens` function which has type `(Monoid w, Monad m) => forall w m a b. MonadWriter w m => (w -> b) -> m a -> m (Tuple a b)`.  If we use `id` in this context the type would be...

```
MonadWriter w m => (w -> b) -> m a -> m (Tuple a b)

w = Array Number
m = WriterT (Array Number) Identity (alias: Writer (Array Number) )
b = Array Number
a = Number

(Array Number -> Array Number) ->
Writer (Array Number) Number ->
Writer (Array Number) (Tuple Number (Array Number))
```

So `listens id` accepts `Writer (Array Number) Number)`, and returns a Writer with the value being the current Writer state (since we used `id`).  However, I keep getting type errors with all the ways I try and use `listens`

```
to1 :: Number -> (Writer (Array Number)) Int
to1 n = do
  v <- (coltzW n)
  -- a <- snd <$> listens id
  -- let l = snd <$> (listens id (execWriter (coltzW n)))
  -- let l = execWriter (listens id (coltzW n))

  -- Seems like this one should work to get Array Number
  -- let l = snd <$> (listens id (coltzW n))

  case (v) of
    1.0 -> pure 1
    _   -> to1 v
```

Edit2:
I figured out what I needed to do.  For some reason I needed to add a type annotation when using `listens`.

```
lengthOfSeq :: Writer (Array Number) Int -> Writer (Array Number) Int
lengthOfSeq c = do
  -- Without type annotation, I get this error...
  -- No type class instance was found for
  --                                                                             
  -- Control.Monad.Writer.Class.MonadWriter (Array t0)                       
  --                                        (WriterT (Array Number) Identity)
  --                                                                             
  -- The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation.
  Tuple a w <- (listens id c :: Writer (Array Number) (Tuple Int (Array Number)))
  pure $ length w

to1 :: Number -> (Writer (Array Number)) Int
to1 n = lengthOfSeq $ seq n
  where
  seq n = do
    v <- coltzW n
    case (v) of
      1.0 -> do
        pure 1
      _   -> seq v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `listens` is the function you're looking for: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-transformers/1.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Writer#v:listens, if I understand correctly what it is you're trying to do.

You can pass `id` in if you're not interested in transforming the value, and if you only want to get hold of the accumulated value then `a <- snd <$> listens id` should do the trick.

Comment: I think I'm missing something with the mechanics of `listens`.  I added an edit about the type signature of listens.  Does my thinking look right to you?  I keep trying variations of using listens, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I figured it out - for some reason I had to add a type annotation when using listens, e.g `a <- snd <$> (listens id c :: Writer (Array Number) (Tuple Int (Array Number)))`  Otherwise I would get error "No type class instance was found for Control.Monad.Writer.Class.MonadWriter (Array t0) (WriterT (Array Number) Identity)"

Comment: Glad you figured it out! The inference with some of these transformers functions is problematic as we don't have functional dependencies currently, but they're coming in the next release (0.10).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the current accumulator. `Writer` is write-only. Use `State` instead of `Writer` if you need the current accumulator. `listen` can only give you the accumulator of a finished computation.